# youtube-dl and --no-mtime what does it mean?

Tags: debian, youtube-dl

I was looking at youtube-dl documentation and it says - -

```
-no-mtime                       Do not use the Last-modified header to set
                                 the file modification time
```

Can anybody tell/share what does that mean in plain english. Does it mean it will respect the time when uploader or youtube has put it or what else does it mean ?

Answer (score 3):

`mtime` is a filesystem field which stores last modified time for file.

When youtube-dl downloads a file, it tries to set file mtime to same as in HTTP Last-Modified header. When `--no-mtime` is used file mtime is not modified manually.

If you are interested in details, you can browse youtube-dl [source code](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/) in github. Some relevant lines:

- Header used to set mtime using `try_utime`: [downloader/http.py: Line 243](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/2017.08.18/youtube_dl/downloader/http.py#L242)
- `try_utime` method in `FileDownloader` class: [downloader/common.py: Line 202](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/2017.08.18/youtube_dl/downloader/common.py#L202)
- Default value for `updatetime`: [options.py: Line 724](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/2017.08.18/youtube_dl/options.py#L724)

Comment: what I'm looking for is to have the original time-stamp i.e. when the video is uploaded. Last few days I'm getting the time-stamp of 'now' rather than the date when it was published on youtube. I have no idea whether that's a bug in youtube-dl or something else.

Comment: youtube-dl uses `Last Modified` header. If you want to manually verify, you can use -v flag for verbose output for youtube-dl. Probably the easiest way to check Last-Modified for urls in youtube-dl output is by using `curl -I`. However youtube-dl documentation allows naming output file with upload date using `-o 'video_%(upload_date)s.flv'` as described by [documentation](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template). If you really need to set `ctime` and/or `mtime` to match you likely need to patch youtube-dl yourself to add such feature.